# What does "$$" mean in the shell?

Tags: command-line

What does the output of the command below mean? (result is positive integer)

```
echo $$
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163144/what-are-the-special-dollar-sign-shell-variables/5163260#5163260 is related

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `$$` variable in bash and other shells contains the process id of the shell.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78493/what-does-mean-in-the-shell) Stack overflow question and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858191/difference-between-bash-pid-and) also has more detail about what it is more precisely, and commands similar to it.

Comment: +1. Documented in the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters)

Answer (score 1):

As the other (accepted) answer indicated, the $ param represents the current process id (PID) of the current shell.

Echoing this param should work in most shells (not just Bash):

Bash:

```
$ echo $0
bash
$ echo $$
6780
```

Bourne:

```
$ echo $0
sh
$ echo $$
6988
```

C-Shell:

```
% echo $shell
/bin/csh
% echo $$
7613
```

It's important to note too, that commands from within the shell will run under the shell's *parent* process id (PPID).

```
$ echo $$
6780
$ ps -ef | grep 6780
aploetz   6780  6770  0 11:15 pts/2    00:00:00 bash
aploetz   8572  6780  0 11:34 pts/2    00:00:00 ps -ef
aploetz   8573  6780  0 11:34 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 6780
```