# What "$$" outputs in command-line?

Tags: command-line

When `$$` typed in terminal, it results in number as follows:

```
$ echo $$
2992
```

So, I want to know what it outputs and what `2992` indicates?

Comment: When I ran echo `$$` I got 26740.

Comment: @karel So, What `26740` indicates?

Comment: process ID as Tim said

Comment: I generated 100 long random numbers, closed the terminal and reopened it and ran `echo $$`. This time I got 31150, the same number as my process ID for the bash process in the System Monitor.

Comment: There is [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858191/difference-between-bash-pid-and) as well. The PID will vary (it changes for different instances of the process), and is assigned to the bash shell. You can see this by running `top -p $$` (you may need to press 'i' if you don't see anything)

Comment: Yes, because it is a different process - a new terminal!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does $$ mean in the shell?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/245425/what-does-mean-in-the-shell) or [Output of echo $$](http://askubuntu.com/questions/442417/output-of-echo)

Comment: @Tuknutx Yes I got it, & I also voted to be **closed as duplicate** because I can't delete as it has Tim's answer!

Comment: Feel free to accept if you still can ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `echo $$` returns the process ID of the terminal or script it was called from.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78493/what-does-mean-in-the-shell) Stack overflow question, where it has already been asked.

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858191/difference-between-bash-pid-and) also has more detail about what it is more precisely, and commands similar to it.

Comment: Yes, It seems related to shell because after switch to `sh` from `bash` it returns different ID.

Comment: Yep, it will do, it's a new process.

Comment: @Pandya - thats because different instances of the same or different program will have different IDs. look in `top` (and my example in the other comment).

Comment: It is a unique way of identifying each process. The name doesn't - e.g. I have about 30 `chrome` processes, but each one has a separate ID, so I can manipulate them individually.

Comment: @Tim As Ultimately we know that it is duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/245425/256099, I want to delete!

Comment: Duplicates are often not deleted, as they will "catch more traffic", i.e. this question might be visited, and they will be redirected. Otherwise it would be asked again and again...